# Be able the users to download / save pdf files from my app on their device - Android App with Java

Tags: android, pdf, save

I am creating an app on Android Studio and I would like to have a few 'downloadable' pdf files on my app. I am creating and updating these pdf files and need my users to have the ability to save them on their devices. I have found a way to make the pdf files 'viewable' from the users through PdfView. I added the files on assets folder and with a button every user is able to read them. Now I want to make them available for save / download. Is there any way to add them on my app and then the users with a button press to save / download them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You added the files to assets for your app. So they are available for your app. I wonder what you have in mind if you want to download a file from assets. Of course you can copy files from assets to storage locations of your device. But why do you want to make such a copy?

Comment: I want to share pdf files through my app. I do not know the best way to do that (I do not know any way actually) but definitely, I want them able to be downloadable / saveable  from the users.  Simple user interface with buttons, the users choose and press the button they want. That press downloads the file that the user wants! That's all! It seems simple to me but I do not know how to implement it..

Comment: You are unclear. Download from where? Where are those files that they can be downloaded?

Comment: I want the files to be on the app! For example on the assets folder or inside any other folder.. from a button which will says "save file 1" the user will be able to save on his device this file..

Comment: I already told you that files packed in the assets folder do not have to be downloaded (from some server on the internet). They can be used directly from assets or they can be copied to device storage. Now please tell what exactly your problem is.

Comment: `For example on the assets folder or inside any other folder.` To be in the assets folder you have to place those files in the assets folder of your project with Android Studio. For any other folder ? Please name those other folders. Where are those folders?

Comment: Ok! My problem is the following.. I placed these pdf files in the Assets folder. Now I want everyone of my users to be able to save any of these files on their device. How is that possible..? For example, when the user press one button the file "sample.pdf" will be saved on his device.. is my question clear? Sorry for not been so clear earlier...

Comment: Copying a file from assets to device storage is pretty elementary and code to do so has been posted a hundred times. A little googling..

Comment: it took me 4 days to figure it out but i did it!
thanks for your help!